# does tensorflow use opencv to covert image to numpy array

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, opencv

Does tensorflow use opencv to covert image to numpy array ? 
How is feature extraction done in tensorflow ? How is it different from opencv model ?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you refer to? Tensorflow is handling all data as Tensors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TensorFlow has two ways of processing image data

1. Built-in Image Ops  ( https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/image )
2. tf.keras Pre-processing ( https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/ )

Feature extraction is at pixels / channel level. Higher level features (Such as Edge / Contrast) are learnt typically by CNN layers.

If needed, you can feed Image Data + Features extracted by OpenCV to TensorFlow.